# BLE double click selection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, onclicklistener

Im writing a BLE app for android as the title says, but when I select a device from my list of discovered devices (my embedded device), the app connects but no data shows up... unless I select it a second time. I know its connecting the first time because the device has an LED indicator but no data comes through until I select it again. Does anyone have any idea why that would be?

```
public class BluetoothDiscovery extends AppCompatActivity {

private String DEVICE = "Bluetooth Device";
private String COMMS = "Bluetooth Communication";
private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 5;

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothLeScannerCompat scanner;
private ScanSettings settings;
private UUID baseUUID = UUID.fromString("6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"); // service UUID
private UUID txUUID = UUID.fromString("6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"); // TX UUID characteristic
private UUID rxUUID = UUID.fromString("6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"); // RX UUID characteristic
private ScanFilter scanFilter;
private BluetoothDevice device, mdevice;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
private boolean mScanning = false;
private ArrayList<deviceShowFormat> foundDevices = new ArrayList<>();
formattingAdapter BTadapter;

Button scanButton;
TextView fancyWords;
ListView deviceList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_discovery);

    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = manager.getAdapter();

    //mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    //mBluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();//.getBluetoothLeScanner();

    scanButton = findViewById(R.id.scanButt);
    scanButton.setText(getString(R.string.notScanning));

    fancyWords = findViewById(R.id.discoverText);
    fancyWords.setText(getString(R.string.nonScanTitle));

    deviceList = findViewById(R.id.deviceList);
    BTadapter = new formattingAdapter(BluetoothDiscovery.this, foundDevices);
    deviceList.setAdapter(BTadapter);


    scanner = BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner();

    settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED).setReportDelay(1000).build();

    scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(baseUUID)).build();

    //scanner.startScan(Arrays.asList(scanFilter), settings, mScanCallback);

    deviceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            scanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            scanButton.setText(getString(R.string.notScanning));

            deviceShowFormat mBTDevice = foundDevices.get(i);

            BluetoothDevice Device = mBTDevice.get_device();
            String deviceName = mBTDevice.get_device_name();
            String deviceAddress = mBTDevice.get_device_address();

            Log.i(DEVICE, "Selected device: " + Device.toString());
            Log.i(DEVICE, "Selected device name: " + deviceName);
            Log.i(DEVICE, "Selected device address: " + deviceAddress);


            mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
            mGatt = Device.connectGatt(BluetoothDiscovery.this, false, mGattCallback);

        }
    });
}

private final no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18.scanner.ScanCallback mScanCallback = new no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18.scanner.ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

        Log.i("onScanResult", "device detected");

        device = result.getDevice();
        String deviceName = device.getName();
        String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();

        Log.i(DEVICE, "Scanned device: " + device.toString());
        Log.i(DEVICE, "Scanned device name: " + deviceName);
        Log.i(DEVICE, "Scanned device address: " + deviceAddress);


        foundDevices.add(new deviceShowFormat(device, deviceName, deviceAddress));
        BTadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};

private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

        Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "State Changed from: " + status + " to " + newState);

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){ // 2
            //Toast.makeText(BluetoothDiscovery.this, "Attempting service discovery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Attempting service discovery: " + mGatt.discoverServices());
            gatt.discoverServices();

        } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED){ // 0
            Toast.makeText(BluetoothDiscovery.this, "Connection has been terminated?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            Log.i("GATT", "Unsuccessful");
            gatt.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status){
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

        Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", "Hey, we found a service");

        List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        Log.i("SERVICE", "Services: " + services.toString());


        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(0);
        //BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(baseUUID).getCharacteristic(rxUUID);


        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);



        List<BluetoothGattDescriptor> describeMe = characteristic.getDescriptors();
        Log.i("DESCRIPTORS", "Descriptors: " + describeMe.toString());
        Log.i("DESCRIPTORS", "Descriptors: " + describeMe.get(1).getUuid().toString());


        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(describeMe.get(0).getUuid());//UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));//describeMe.get(1).getUuid()
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

        Log.i("ByeSERVICESDISCOVERED", "that");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        Log.i("onCharacteristicChanged", "Entered");

        byte[] dataInput = characteristic.getValue();
        Log.i("MESSAGE", dataInput.toString());

        try {
            String data = new String(dataInput, "UTF-8");

            // create list to contain data

            Log.i("MESSAGE2", data);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.i("onCharacteristicChanged", "Bye");
    }

};

public void toggleScan(View view){
    mScanning = !mScanning;

    if(mScanning){
        scanner.startScan(mScanCallback); //Arrays.asList(scanFilter) null, settings,
        scanButton.setText(getString(R.string.scanInProgress));
        fancyWords.setText(getString(R.string.ScanTitle));

    } else {
        scanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        scanButton.setText(getString(R.string.notScanning));
        //foundDevices.clear();
    }
}



}
```

Log output on first click
[image]

Log output on second click
[image]

Marked in red are my logs for debugging

Comment: I have seen the following situation with Microchip RN4020 -- on first power-up, it connects, but does not receive data (characteristic updates).  Since I am sending a request for data, I time-out, close the connection, then set it up again.  It always seems to work the 2nd and subsequent time.  This is usually the case on iOS, and very consistent on Android (using Xamarin) and on Windows using an external BLE dongle (Bluegiga BLED112).  So, please answer or comment if you get an update.

Comment: The chip im using is the nRF51822, on the adafruit ble flora device. When I connect using other apps from the app store it connects right away which is why i figure its something in my code. I am using notifications, not read, would it still be requesting? Im using android studio for my coding.

Comment: @bobwki click is because on the first click the data from the device has not yet reached the android device. In short you have to block with a timeout until the round trip is completed. I have posted a BLE android code example (First pass, more work is needed) [here](https://github.com/mahengunawardena/ShapeTheWorld).